# How do I call functions from C dll from SSIS ? or, how to load a C dll to GAc

Tags: unmanaged, gac, ssis

I am creating a custom DTS Pipeline component for SSIS. This component calls a C# dll which is a wrapper around a C dll. Basically the C# wrapper defines the C dll functions' signatures and uses DllImport attribute.

The problem is that to use this in SSIS, I need both the C# wrapper and my C dll to be in GAC... How can I load the C dll of unmanaged code to GAC? Or what alternative solution do I have? PS: I have the source code of the C dll...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually didn't need to put it in GAC. It just needed to be in runtime path: "%systemroot%\System32"... Thanks anyways

Comment: I prefer to use %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn, it is closer to the source (use 90 for 2005, 110 for 2011). I believe there's a registry entry that will tell you exactly where SSIS is installed.